# flask Form is not validating after submit in flask and im using flaskpickr for datetime picker

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flatpickr

i put an print statement under of the `if form.validate_on_submit():` it seems its not printing and i think the error comes from the `date = form.date.data` because it is recently added

```
@app.route('/book', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def book_appointment():
    form = AppointmentForm()
    print("creating form")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("Form is Validate on submit")
        branch = form.branch.data
        service = form.service.data
        date = form.date.data

        # Create a new instance of the Book_date model
        appointment = Book_date(branch=branch, service=service, date=date, user_id=current_user.id)

        # Add the new instance to the database and commit changes
        db.session.add(appointment)
        db.session.commit()

        # Redirect to a success page
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('book.html', form=form)
```

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
          {{ form.date.label(class="form-label") }}
          {{ form.date(class="form-control",id="date-picker") }}

        </div>
</form

<script>
flatpickr("#date-picker", {
    enableTime: true,
      minDate: "tomorrow",
      disable: [
      {
        from: "2000-01-01",
        to: new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]
      }
      ],
      time_24hr: false,
      dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
      minTime: "10:00",
      maxTime: "16:00",
      defaultHour: 10,
      defaultMinute: 0
});
</script>
```

```
class AppointmentForm(FlaskForm):


    branch = SelectField('Branch', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[('','Select your       Branch'),('FCM','Fairview Center Mall Branch'),('Zapote','Zapote Branch')])
    
    service = SelectField('Type of Services', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[('','What type of service do you want?'),('Haircut with style','Haircut with style')])

    
    default_time = datetime.combine(datetime.today(), time(hour=9))

      date = DateTimeField('Appointment Date & Time', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M', validators=[DataRequired()], widget=DateTimeInput())    
    submit = SubmitField('Book')

    submit_another = SubmitField('Paynow')

    def validate_date_time(form, field):
        start_time = time(hour=9)
        if field.data.time() < start_time:
            raise ValidationError('Appointment time must start at 9 am.')
```

I check my other forms its all fine it accepting and validating, the database is fine

Im trying to create a form with a date and time picker that with a default of 10am and can only appointment the next day and can start 10am to 4pm only

Comment: 1. what does the HTTP request data look like? (you can see it in Chrome developer tools)
2. print out `request.form` before `validate_on_submit()`, what do you see?
3. this might be an issues with CSRF. try temporarily disabling it
4. do you really need that js tool? why not use `DateTimeLocalField`?

Comment: I use 'DateTimeLocalField' earlier and it works perfectly but i want in my picker disable or not clickable the past/present days and can only submit the date and time the next day. is it possible to have that functionality in 'DateTimeLocalField'?

Comment: you can set the min and max of the DateTimeLocalField, so yes, like `myfield = DateTimeLocalField("somedate", render_kw={"min": somevar, "max": someothervar})`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#additional_attributes